# Unable to deserialize kafka events in NestJs

Tags: javascript, apache-kafka, nestjs

I have the following configuration, in main and controller file. I have an external kafka

I have defined the microservice in the `main.ts`

```
  app.connectMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>({
    transport: Transport.KAFKA,
    options: {
      client: {
        brokers: ['localhost:9092'],
      },
      consumer: {
        groupId: 'consumer-1',
      },
    },
  });
  await app.startAllMicroservices();
  app.useGlobalPipes(
    new ValidationPipe({
      transform: true,
    }),
  );
```

In the `controller.ts`

```
export class Controller implements OnModuleInit {
  constructor(private readonly service: Service) {}

  @Client({
    transport: Transport.KAFKA,
    options: {
      client: {
        brokers: ['localhost:9092'],
      },
      consumer: {
        groupId: 'consumer-1',
      },
    },
  })
  client: ClientKafka;

  async onModuleInit() {
    this.client.subscribeToResponseOf('topic-tx');
    await this.client.connect();
    Logger.log(
      'consumer assignments: ' +
        JSON.stringify(this.client.getConsumerAssignments()),
    );
  }

  @MessagePattern('topic-tx', Transport.KAFKA)
  async handleEntityCreated(@Payload('value') message: IResponseValue) {
    console.log('Received event: ', message);
  }
```

The events from kafka topic is printed on the console as buffer, and it is not de-serializing appropriately.

```
Received event:  $da4fa4c3-9e91-43d9-acaa-a07d1fed2635"�
*0x5bcd9e419a11AB71f5eea1a2CFf9B0694C990Baf29*0xDFB50936C5d83b8367BDC01B17c386203AA60368*4611920x0:�0xd3fc98640000000000000000000000005bcd9e419a11ab71f5eea1a2cff9b0694c990baf00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000380000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000060000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004034346532343639353263666337363430663535306162386233343363633564633865623033303937373534343030343935306134646432393134663864663561B�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�legacy*�
B0x02dff5ee07b16609c959660789dd743d648a5f44f4ad3651fefe76f7ee004134B0x362711a341c6e4647f8978a9bb01df8097d9dd9177989389fc17627c66ee1615�%@R�0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000040000000000000000000012000000000000000110000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000800000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008000000000000000020000004000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200080000000800Z�
*0xDFB50936C5d83b8367BDC01B17c386203AA60368B0xc3d58168c5ae7397731d063d5bbf3d657854427343f4c083240f7aacaa2d0f62B0x0000000000000000000000005bcd9e419a11ab71f5eea1a2cff9b0694c990bafB0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000B0x0000000000000000000000005bcd9e419a11ab71f5eea1a2cff9b0694c990baf�0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000380000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001"7TransferSingle(address,address,address,uint256,uint256)*2
from*0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000*0
to*0x5bcd9e419a11AB71f5eea1a2CFf9B0694C990Baf*
id56*

value1*6
operator*0x5bcd9e419a11AB71f5eea1a2CFf9B0694C990Baf0�%:B0x02dff5ee07b16609c959660789dd743d648a5f44f4ad3651fefe76f7ee004134JB0x362711a341c6e4647f8978a9bb01df8097d9dd9177989389fc17627c66ee1615Z�
*0xDFB50936C5d83b8367BDC01B17c386203AA60368B0x6bb7ff708619ba0610cba295a58592e0451dee2622938c8755667688daf3529bB0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000038�0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004034346532343639353263666337363430663535306162386233343363633564633865623033303937373534343030343935306134646432393134663864663561"URI(string,uint256)*I
value@44e246952cfc7640f550ab8b343cc5dc8eb030977544004950a4dd2914f8df5a*
id560�%:B0x02dff5ee07b16609c959660789dd743d648a5f44f4ad3651fefe76f7ee004134JB0x362711a341c6e4647f8978a9bb01df8097d9dd9177989389fc17627c66ee1615P`��h��r0x0�
MetalToken�latest:devB$0afcfd48-c20b-4db7-ab35-73f90e937c37
```

How to deserialize the incoming message from kafka broker into appropriate interface

Comment: Seems like it's deserializing to UTF8 perfectly fine... Do you control the producer code? If not, you'll need to ask them what serialization format they're using since it doesn't appear to be textual format

Comment: no, i dont control the producer code, i have the serialization format, but nestjs seems to nt deserializing it appropriately to the passed format

Comment: And what format is that? Like I said, seems you're printing utf8, but the producer isn't sending plaintext data, so you can't just print the message value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The more i explored into nestjs kafka client code, i found the solution to my problem. Also, this https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/3726 helped me resolve the issue.

The exact issue was : In Kafka Microservice Buffer values are always stringified, which was prohibiting the parsing to the right format.

The solution is to set parser options: keepBinary as true in the kafkaconfig, so as to preserve the buffer format.

```
{
  transport: Transport.KAFKA,

  options: {
    client: {
      brokers: ['localhost:9092'],
    },
    consumer: {
      groupId: 'consumer-1',
    },
    parser: { keepBinary: true },
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your data has a custom format, you can setup a custom deserializer like the following:

```
import { Deserializer } from '@nestjs/microservices';

export class CustomDeserializer implements Deserializer {
  public deserialize(data: Buffer): unknown {
    const stringifiedData = data.toString();
    
    // do stuff here...

    return deserializedData;
  }
}
```

After that, you can inject that deserializer in your microservice with the following:

```js
  app.connectMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>({
    transport: Transport.KAFKA,
    options: {
      deserializer: new CustomDeserializer();
      client: {
        brokers: ['localhost:9092'],
      },
      consumer: {
        groupId: 'consumer-1',
      },
    },
  });
  await app.startAllMicroservices();
```